# Ubuntu - trying to delete a file that has no inode

Tags: ubuntu, files, directory, rm, inode

I try to delete a file that is left in a directory, but even an ls -i will not give me an inode to remove it. Deleting/removing the directory won't work even with the inode.

```
$ ls -ila
ls: cannot access 'Mieterh'$'\3.webarchive': No such file or directory
total 0
1477265 drwxr-xr-x 1 99 99 3 Feb 18 08:49  .
1477260 drwxr-xr-x 1 99 99 3 Feb  2  2023  ..
      ? -????????? ? ?  ?  ?            ? 'Mieterh
```

This is an external drive mounted using a USB connection.

```
filesystem: HFS+ 
OpSys: Ubuntu 22.04.03
Size: 5TB
Space left: about 1 TB
Vendor: Toshiba
```

thanks in advance for any help/advice.

Probably it's the easiest to delete the directory with the including "garbage"... but how?

Comment: I removed the screenshot of text that you added. Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086).

Comment: There's no such thing as deleting a file through an inode number, all the relevant system calls only accept filenames. If the filename is found in a listing, but can't be accessed, then the filesystem is broken one way or the other. At least from the point of view of the OS on that system. HFS+ seems it might hint at a Mac, so maybe the drive and FS will work better on one instead.

Comment: `fsck_hfs` is probably worth a try,  but this directory entry may be of a type not understood by Ubuntu.

Comment: This file **does** have an inode, it's just `ls` cannot access it (it has an invalid name), thus it cannot read the inode number. To me the filesystem just looks corrupted. Please run fsck.